# AttributeError: 'UserProfile object has no attribute 'artist_category' django

Tags: python, django

I have three models I am trying to create Artist and UserProfile when users register this part works fine and I also want to update Artist model when I update UserProfile.

models.py:

custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     artist_choice = [
        (0, 'celebrities'),
        (1, 'singer'),
    (2, 'comedian'),
    (3, 'dancer'),
    (4, 'model'),
    (5, 'Photographer')

]
    artist_category = models.IntegerField(choices=artist_choice, null=True)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)   
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]

objects=UserManager()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/users/%i/" % (self.pk)
```

artist model:

```
class Artist(models.Model):
     CHOICES = (
        (0, 'celebrities'),
        (1, 'singer'),
        (2, 'comedian'),
        (3, 'dancer'),
        (4, 'model'),
        (5, 'Photographer')
   )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist_category = models.IntegerField(choices = CHOICES, null=True)
    artist_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'media',null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length = 500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

userprofile model:

```
  class UserProfile(models.Model):
        CHOICES = (
             (0, 'celebrities'),
            (1, 'singer'),
           (2, 'comedian'),
          (3, 'dancer'),
           (4, 'model'),
            (5, 'Photographer')
)
      user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='userprofile', on_delete= models.CASCADE)

      image = models.FileField(upload_to=None, max_length=100)
      artist_category = models.IntegerField(choices= CHOICES, null=True)
      mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
      country = CountryField(default = 'IN')
      city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)   
      bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.name
```

creating profile after user register:

```
def create_profile(sender,**kwargs ):
     if kwargs['created']:        
        user_profile=UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = kwargs['instance'])


     post_save.connect(create_profile,sender=CustomUser)
```

this is the part when i am getting error:

```
  @receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser)
  def create_user_artist(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
      if created:
         data = {
            'name': instance.name,           
        }
      Artist.objects.create(**data)
      
      

  @receiver(post_save,sender=UserProfile)
  def update_user_artist(sender, **kwargs):
      instance = kwargs['instance']

      instance.artist.artist_category = instance.artist_category

      instance.artist.save()
```

I am trying to get the name when users register and artist_category when I update the profile but its shows error.

Comment: You have a `UserProfile`, not a `CustomUser`.

Comment: i forgot to add userprofile model

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear in itself, you are trying to access `artist_category` with `UserProfile` object.

Need to give a foreign relation `UserProfile` with `Artist`.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        CHOICES = (
             (0, 'celebrities'),
            (1, 'singer'),
           (2, 'comedian'),
          (3, 'dancer'),
           (4, 'model'),
            (5, 'Photographer')
)
      user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='userprofile', on_delete= models.CASCADE)

      image = models.FileField(upload_to=None, max_length=100)
      artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist,related_name='user_artist')
      artist_category = models.IntegerField(choices= CHOICES, null=True)
      mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
      country = CountryField(default = 'IN')
      city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)   
      bio = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.name
```

Make it -

```
 @receiver(post_save,sender=CustomUser)
  def update_user_artist(sender, **kwargs):
      instance = kwargs['instance']

      instance.artist.artist_category = instance.artist_category

      instance.artist.save()
```

Comment: CustomUser object has not attribute artist

Comment: trying to populate artist model  artist_category when i update the UserProfile artist_category

Comment: it stil raising error CustomUser has not attribute artist btw artist_category changed when userprofile update so sender should be UserProfile i tried that also